# How to print boxplots for each row of a dataset in R?

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

Here's an example data and I was wondering as to what should I do if I want to boxplot stock1, stock2, stock 3 and stock 4,  for Day1, Day2... Day6 seperately, in R?

```
head(StockExample)
    X1 Stock1 Stock2 Stock3 Stock4
1 Day1 185.74   1.47   1605  95.05
2 Day2 184.26   1.56   1580  97.49
3 Day3 162.21   1.39   1490  88.57
4 Day4 159.04   1.43   1520  85.55
5 Day5 164.87   1.42   1550  92.04
6 Day6 162.72   1.36   1525  91.70
```

So 6 boxplots for each of the days, with stock 1-4 in each of those boxplots. Hope I'm making sense. Also, can I do this using the apply function?

I tried looking up for an answer for this, but couldn't get it right. Appreciate any help in this regard. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A good practice to develop would be to 'gather' the stock columns. Something like the following should work. (But I've not tested this.)

```
require(tidyverse)
require(stringr)

StockExample %>% 
    tidyr::gather(key = "Stock", value = "value", -X1) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(day = stringr::str_replace(X1, "Day", "") %>% as.numeric() ) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(Stock = stringr::str_replace(Stock, "Stock", "") %>% as.numeric() ) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = day, y = value)) +
    geom_boxplot()
```

(The code above uses scoping, `packagename::functionname`, to indicate specific functions within the tidyverse used to perform some of the operations.

Comment: Your solution works except you should add `colour = X1` in aes. Here is the data: `structure(list(X1 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Day1", "Day2", 
"Day3", "Day4", "Day5", "Day6"), class = "factor"), Stock1 = c(185.74, 
184.26, 162.21, 159.04, 164.87, 162.72), Stock2 = c(1.47, 1.56, 
1.39, 1.43, 1.42, 1.36), Stock3 = c(1605L, 1580L, 1490L, 1520L, 
1550L, 1525L), Stock4 = c(95.05, 97.49, 88.57, 85.55, 92.04, 
91.7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))` was just about to put an answer but you were faster.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this, both of the above require that the data be in long format.
In order to reformat the data I will use function `melt` from package `reshape2`.

```
long <- reshape2::melt(StockExample, id.var = "X1")
```

Now the graphs.

First, using base R graphics.

```
boxplot(value ~ X1, long)
```

And second, with package `ggplot2`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(long, aes(X1, value)) +
    geom_boxplot()
```

**Data.**

```
StockExample <-
structure(list(X1 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Day1", "Day2", 
"Day3", "Day4", "Day5", "Day6"), class = "factor"), Stock1 = c(185.74, 
184.26, 162.21, 159.04, 164.87, 162.72), Stock2 = c(1.47, 1.56, 
1.39, 1.43, 1.42, 1.36), Stock3 = c(1605L, 1580L, 1490L, 1520L, 
1550L, 1525L), Stock4 = c(95.05, 97.49, 88.57, 85.55, 92.04, 
91.7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data in long format and then it's straightforward with `ggstatsplot`:

```r
# needed libraris
library(tidyverse)
library(ggstatsplot)

# provided data sample
df <- read.table(
  text = "Row Day Stock1 Stock2 Stock3 Stock4
  1 Day1 185.74   1.47   1605  95.05
  2 Day2 184.26   1.56   1580  97.49
  3 Day3 162.21   1.39   1490  88.57
  4 Day4 159.04   1.43   1520  85.55
  5 Day5 164.87   1.42   1550  92.04
  6 Day6 162.72   1.36   1525  91.70",
  header = TRUE
) %>%
  tibble::as_data_frame()

# converting to long format
(
  df_long <- df %>%
    tidyr::gather(
      data = .,
      key = "stock type",
      value = "stock value",
      Stock1:Stock4
    )
)
#> # A tibble: 24 x 4
#>      Row Day   `stock type` `stock value`
#>    <int> <fct> <chr>                <dbl>
#>  1     1 Day1  Stock1              186.  
#>  2     2 Day2  Stock1              184.  
#>  3     3 Day3  Stock1              162.  
#>  4     4 Day4  Stock1              159.  
#>  5     5 Day5  Stock1              165.  
#>  6     6 Day6  Stock1              163.  
#>  7     1 Day1  Stock2                1.47
#>  8     2 Day2  Stock2                1.56
#>  9     3 Day3  Stock2                1.39
#> 10     4 Day4  Stock2                1.43
#> # ... with 14 more rows

# plot
ggstatsplot::ggbetweenstats(
  data = df_long,
  x = Day,
  y = `stock value`,
  plot.type = "box"
)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-08-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is probably splitting the `data.frame` by row:

```
byDay <- split(StockExample[,-1], StockExample$X1)
```

Then convert all of those into numeric format:

```
byDay <- lapply(byDay, as.numeric)
```

And then simply call `boxplot` on it:

```
boxplot(byDay)
```

---

Or with everything in one line:

```
boxplot(lapply(split(StockExample[,-1], StockExample$X1), as.numeric))
```

[image]